# Tab navigation in MFCProprtyGridCtrol

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am working in an MFC windows application. I am using Grid control with some icons and its properties are displaying with MFC Property Grid Control ( `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` ). I need to implement tab navigation. I i am in some icon (let us assume "Star1") and when I press tab key it should go to its properties control ( MFC Property grid control) and focus on any field or group name.

I did try to capture keyboard events in `PretranslateMessage()`. but needs how to set focus on that specific field or group name?

[image]

Comment: It does support tab navigation. Make sure `WS_TABSTOP` is set. Once grid control has focus, use up/down arrow key to switch between the controls. If the focused item in PropertyGridCtrl is scrolled out of view (that might be the problem in your case) then the focused item will not be visible. You might have to drive your own class from `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` to deal with these issues. But it's hard to think of a tab switch scheme which is perfect.

Comment: That is what we are using but we need elegant solution like tab switch scheme. End user don't know all these stuff.